# Common model in Codeigniter with HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, hmvc-codeigniter

i've been use codeigniter with hmvc pattern.my folder structure is something like below
[image]

**Now question is how can i use `adminw` model in common codeigniter model ?**

i've common controller which is as follow

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        //here i am checking url if adminw than load model inside adminw folder
        $path = $this->uri->segment(1);
        if($path != ADMIN_FOLDER){
            $this->load->model('modules/SettingModel');<-- BUT THIS IS NOT WORKING
        }else{
            $this->load->model('SettingModel');
        }
```

in short how can i load model that is stored in hmvc folder

Answer (score 1):

If your model in..

modules > admin > models > mdl_admin.php

then you can use it in any module's controllers as like..

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('admin/mdl_admin','controllers_relevant_module_name');
    ....
    ....
}
```

*admin - Its module name,*

*mdl_admin - model name (admin->models->mdl_admin.php),*

*controllers_relevant_module_name - controller relevant module*

Its just for reference.. you may modify as per your code flow requirements

Comment: thats why I added the last tip.. its just for reference..

Comment: that didn't worked for me still same error persist

Comment: this worked for me
$this->load->model("module01/models01"); from duplicate

Comment: as per your screenshot, in which folder you've placed your model

Comment: check edits, explained in brief